# How to combine results from two different Lucene Indexes?

Tags: solr, lucene, pentaho, jboss-portal, gatein

Use case:

- JBoss Portal / Gatein
- Pentaho BI

Both have Lucene based search built on top of them. As a user I need to see both Portal Content and BI Reports for my search query.

**Is there a way to query both and then combine the results?**

Schema and configuration is different for both Indexes I assume so Merging or Solr Distributed Search options don't seem to fit.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing out of the box. Since: when the schema (documents) are different, how should the scoring be accomplished or be set in relation to each other? This is something you need to think about. Then you can write code to deliver merged results.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement this on your logic layer by providing some Wrapper service that will get results from both systems and then combines results.